# Why wont my jar run using the full path?

Tags: linux, bash, jar, path, zip

I have a `.jar` file (`~/koba/loki.jar`) that I'm trying to examine in a bash script.

I'm inside `~/foobar` folder while running the script but when the script runs the following command:

`jar -tvf ~/koba/loki.jar` it errors out and doesn't run:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:116)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:1004)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:245)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
```

Why doesn't the jar command work?  When I `ls` the file it works successfully (and has a valid size) but the jar command can't even find it and says it's empty.

If I give: `jar -tvf ../koba/loki.jar` -- then it works fine!! (i.e. if I use relative path to the jar file from my current folder location).

Comment: Would you mind posting your script?

Comment: my script has only 1 line in it and that I have mentioned above. #!/bin/bash (first line) and 2nd line says: jar -tvf ~/koba/lori.jar